# Storing database data in the Document/View architecture

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, view, mfc, document

I was wondering: if the Model class should store the data related to a database (and also be able to connect with it and perform sql queries - in order to retrieve some data, for example) in projects that follow the MVC design pattern, should the Document class in the Document/View architecture be used for the same purpose? Or maybe it would be better to create an auxiliar class to perform all the database connections and data storage?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need one or more auxiliary classes to query and fetch recordsets, but these classes should be members of the document class to fit in with the GUI updating mechanism inherent in the Document/View architecture. (I.e., call UpdateAllViews when new data becomes available.)

Comment: Why would I need these auxiliary classes, exactly?

Comment: @Mudkip: Because whatever database access method/API you use will put the data into an auxiliary object, like a CRecordset. The database interface will not be able to put the data directly into your CDocument object.

Answer (score 0):

I use the document to hold the Connection to the database or the representation of the current record (or let us say: entity), that should be modified/altered.
The views show the visual representation of this record/entity.

So the "record" may consist out of more records in different tables...